# How can I take an array of numbers and get a string like this: "1-3, 5, 6"?

Tags: php, arrays, string, format

I have a rather odd problem. I have an app that takes an array of numbers between one and six. They could be in any number of patterns. From there, I want them formatted in a specific way. It's a bit hard to explain, so I'll just give you some examples:

```
[1] -> "1" (duh!)
[1, 3] -> "1,3" (any two values will be separated by commas)
[1, 2, 3] -> "1-3" (consecutive series: lowest and highest values separated by a dash)
[1, 3, 4] -> "1, 3, 4" (non-consecutive series: separated by commas)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6] -> 1-3, 5, 6" (mixed: consecutive series and non-consecutive series as you see)
```

A few other parameters:

- Each item in the array is unique
- The list will be pre-sorted

The app is written in PHP.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no inbuilt function to do things like this you have to use some tricks with PHP range function

Comment: So far, I've tried a number of things involving iterating through the array and putting the values into a string, with consecutive values getting skipped. Unfortunately, one thing or another keeps gumming it up. I'm starting to think that I'd like to turn the consecutive values into substrings formatted like I showed above and then imploding the array (e.g.: ["1-3", 5, 6]) but I really don't know how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delayed by a sudden Internet error...

```
function compound(array $arr)
{
    $cache=array();
    $rst="";
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        if(empty($cache) || $v==end($cache)+1)
        {
            $cache[]=$v;
        }
        else
        {
            if(!empty($rst)) $rst.=",";
            if(count($cache)>2) $rst.=reset($cache)."-".end($cache);
            else $rst.=implode(",",$cache);
            $cache=array($v);
        }
    }
    if(!empty($rst)) $rst.=",";
    if(count($cache)>2) $rst.=reset($cache)."-".end($cache);
    else $rst.=implode(",",$cache);
    return $rst;
}
echo compound(array(1,2,3,5,6))."\n"; // gets "1-3,5,6"
echo compound(array(1,3,4,5,6)); // gets "1,3-6"
```

[Live demo](http://3v4l.org/HdM0G)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that does what you wanted, and tested it with your examples.

PS: Here is the codepad with the tests: http://codepad.org/hz9cHOvr#output

```
function getString($arr, $range = 1)
{
    if (!is_array($arr)) {
        return '';
    }

    // reset array keys
    $arr = array_values($arr);

    // simple cases
    if (count($arr) <= 2) {
        return implode(',', $arr);
    }

    $len = count($arr);
    $rez = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i ++) {
        $rangeLength = 1;
        $nextI = $i;
        $stop = 0;
        while (!$stop) { // loop to see if we find a range
            if ($arr[$nextI + 1] - $arr[$nextI] == $range) {
                $nextI ++;
                $rangeLength ++;
                $stop = 0;
            } else {
                $stop = 1;
            }
        }
        if ($rangeLength >= 3) { // either add the range
            $rez .= $arr[$i] . '-' . $arr[$nextI] . ', ';
            $i = $nextI;
        } else { // or the number
            $rez .= $arr[$i] . ', ';
        }
    }
    return substr($rez, 0, strlen($rez) - 2); // strip last 2 chars (the comma and space)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution :

```
$array    = array(1,3,5,6);

function checkConsec($d) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($d);$i++) {
        if(isset($d[$i+1]) && $d[$i]+1 != $d[$i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

$temp     = array();
$res      = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    $temp[]  = $array[$i];
    if(checkConsec($temp) && count($temp) > 1){
       $res[$temp[0]] = $temp[0]."-".$temp[count($temp)-1];
    }else{
       $res[$array[$i]] = $array[$i];
       $temp     = array();
       $temp[]  = $array[$i];
    }
}

echo implode(",",$res);
```

For the given input (`array(1,3,5,6)`) output will be `1,3,5-6`

Comment: This is also really good, but like I said, Passerby's solution was a bit more concise. Still, I appreciate your help. Thank you.